# Delete Dynamic Allocate array inside a class

Tags: c++, memory

```
Class name{
private:
int *ptr=new ptr[10];

public:
//do some thing
~name(){
      delete ptr; //should I do this?
  }
};
```

After creating this class, if I go out of the scope, should I write a destructor that automatically handles this dynamically allocated integer array?

Comment: Yes. All "new" should have a "delete" call.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must free any memory you allocate.  But memory allocated with `new[]` must be freed using `delete[]`, not `delete`.

```
class name {
private:
    int *ptr = new ptr[10];

public:
    //...

    ~name() {
        delete[] ptr;
    }
};
```

What you *should* do is use a `std::vector` or `std::array` instead, and let it handle the memory management for you.

```
class name {
private:
    std::vector<int> ptr{10};

public:
    //...
};
```

```
class name {
private:
    std::array<int, 10> ptr;

public:
    //...
};
```

Comment: So if I declare it as local variable (local to the class), upon the class object destruction, the local variable will be automatically destroyed?

Comment: @NygenPatricia yes. Non-pointer class members are destructed when their containing class is destructed.